# EOF error when using sql query in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am getting an  error here on this Snowflake query and am not sure what is incorrect.
Not quite sure why I would have an issue, so was hoping for some help.

Any ideas?

```
  SELECT 
      EXTRACT (YEAR FROM t1.DOC_POST_DT) AS sap_post_year,
      t1.FISCL_YR_MO_NBR AS fiscal_year,
      t1.DOC_POST_DT AS post_date,
      t1.DOC_CRTE_DT AS doc_date,
      t1.CRTED_DT as created_date,
      t2.COST_CNTR_WO_ZEROS_CD AS cost_center,
      t2.COST_CNTR_NM cost_center_name,
      t2.COST_ELEM_WO_ZEROS_CD AS cost_element,
      t2.COST_ELEM_NM AS cost_element_name,
      t1.ORD_NBR AS Internal_order,
      t1.ACCTG_DOC_TYP_CD AS doc_type,
      t3.VNDR_NM AS vendor_name,
      t1.t1_LN_ITEM_DSC AS description,
      t1.CRTED_BY_NM AS created_by,
      t1.LCL_CRNCY_DBT_CR_AMT AS amount
  
  
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 
    ON (t1.COST_CNTR_CD = t2.COST_CNTR_CD AND t1.t1_ACCT_NBR = t2.COST_ELEM_CD)
    AND (t2.COST_CNTR_WO_ZEROS_CD = '1292081800')
    AND (t2.COST_ELEM_WO_ZEROS_CD = '860379')
    
    
LEFT JOIN table3 t3
    ON (t1.t3NDR_ID = t3.t3NDR_ID)
    
WHERE (t1.FISCL_YR_MO_NBR BETWEEN 2021001 AND to_number(to_char(current_date, 'YYYYMMDD'))
AND (t1.t1_LN_ITEM_DSC LIKE '%TIE%');
```

Comment: Please also post error you are getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a closing parenthesis on your to_number. Should be

```
(t1.FISCL_YR_MO_NBR BETWEEN 2021001 AND to_number(to_char(current_date, 'YYYYMMDD')))
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks. Dumb mistake on my part

Comment: Happens to us all!